# How to check if the current user has the permission to create a database view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I want to check if `CURRENT_USER()` has the permission to create a `VIEW` on a certain MySQL database xyz.

To do so, I run

`SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER()`

Depending on how the grants are set, the output rows can be different.
If a row contains the following strings, I assume that the user has the `CREATE VIEW` permission.

I have seen the following variants, are there other ones?

```
CREATE VIEW
ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*
ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xyz`.*
```

Or is there another/better way to check this?

Comment: *I want to check if CURRENT_USER() has the permission to create a VIEW on a certain MySQL database xyz.* I think that the attempt to create some fake view is more simple way.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509921/how-to-check-if-the-current-user-has-the-permission-to-create-a-database-view-in